# removing the current listener from within EventM

Tags: javascript, haskell, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

Suppose I want to create, using ghcjs-dom, an event listener which responds to a click, and then removes itself.

I have

```hs
addListener :: (IsEventTarget t, IsEvent e)
            => t -> EventName t e -> SaferEventListener t e -> Bool -> IO ()
```

```hs
removeListener :: (IsEventTarget t, IsEvent e)
            => t -> EventName t e -> SaferEventListener t e -> Bool -> IO ()
```

to add and remove, and

```hs
newListener :: (IsEvent e) => EventM t e () -> IO (SaferEventListener t e)
```

to construct the listener out of an `EventM`. How can I access the `SaferEventListener` (which I will only later construct) from within the `EventM`, in order to remove it when the event occurs?

In JavaScript, you use a named function expression as your callback to `addEventListener`, and then apply `removeEventListener` to that name from within the callback. But nothing analogus seems to be possible here. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fixIO`

```hs
fixIO $ \rec -> newListener _eventm
```

Fill `_eventm` with your `EventM`, and you will be able to access the event listener that will eventually be created through the name `rec`. `rec` will be the result of the `newListener` call, but it can be "used" before that is executed. I say "used," because trying to force it with `seq` or anything stronger will cause an infinite loop, but you should be fine doing what you're doing.

---

`fixIO` is a generalization of `fix`:

```hs
-- the essence of recursion
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
-- equivalent but less performant and less relevant
fix f = f (fix f)

-- if you have used JS's "named anonymous functions"
-- this will seem very familiar
(fix (\fact n ->
  if n <= 1 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1)
)) 3 = 6
-- JS:
-- (function fact(n) {
--   if(n <= 1) { return 1; } else { return n * fact(n - 1); }
-- })(3) === 6

-- but this has more power
repeat = fix . (:)
repeat 1 = fix (1:) = 
   let x = 1:x in x = 1:fix (1:) = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...]

fix id = let x = id x in x = let x = x in x = _|_ -- oops!

fixIO :: (a -> IO a) -> IO a
fixIO f = _ -- horrendous, unsafe code

fixIO (\xs -> return $ 1:xs) = return [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...]

fixIO return = fixIO (return . id) = return $ fix id = return _|_ -- oops!
```

The idea of `fix` is making a function's eventual result available to it before it is actually created.
The idea of `fixIO` is making an `IO` function's eventual result available to it before it is actually created *while also carrying out some `IO` actions*. Also, `fixIO` only carries out these actions *once*, which is why the first definition of `fix` (that only calls `f` once) is more relevant than the second.

`fixIO`, in turn, is a specialization of `mfix :: MonadFix m => (a -> m a) -> m a`, where `MonadFix` is the class of monads (including `IO`, with `mfix = fixIO`) that admit such knot-tying semantics. GHC supports "recursive `do`" notation for any `MonadFix`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
someCode = mdo ...
               listener <- newListener _eventm -- can access listener in definition
               ...
-- or
someCode = do ...
              rec listener <- newListener _eventm
              ...
```